# Select One Column Using Peewee

Tags: python, mysql, flask, orm, peewee

I have selected one column by using the peewee, and then send it to the template. But nothing return.

I have one table named Entry, with column tag_name.

```
@app.route('/archive')
def tag():
    query_tag = (Entry.select(Entry.tag_name)).distinct())
    return object_list('t.html', query_tag, check_bounds=False)
```

The corresponding template:

```
{%block content %}
{% for tag in object_list %}
    <p>{{ tag }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

And finally it display "None"
[result_photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAmQl.png)

But if I change to below code, it can work,:

```
@app.route('/archive')
def tag():
    query_tag = (Entry.select().distinct())
    return object_list('t.html', query_tag, check_bounds=False)
```

And the template:

```
{%block content %}
{% for tag in object_list %}
    <p>{{ tag.tag_name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine your two examples and the following should work:

```
query_tag = Entry.select(Entry.tag_name).distinct()
```

And the template:

```
{% for entry in object_list %}
    <p>{{ entry.tag_name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Because, even though you've only selected one column, Peewee will still be returning `Entry` objects. The `Entry` objects will only have the "tag_name" field populated, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got it.

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct then? Or upvote it or whatever?

Comment: Thanks coleifer. I try to upvote it, but it display:Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.